# How do I execute doble LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, oledb

I need your help today :)

I'm trying to execute an SQL instruction using c#:

```
 "SELECT table_organe.id,table_famille.famille,table_organe.Libelle,table_organe.Description,table_organe.Symbole, rle_orgposition.position " + "FROM (table_organe " +
    "LEFT JOIN table_famille ON table_organe.Famille= table_famille.ID) " +   "LEFT JOIN rle_orgposition ON table_organe.id = rle_orgposition.idOrgane";
```

It appears that is not working, I've tried with brackets,etc.
The only instruction that works is :

```
SELECT * " +
"FROM (table_organe " +
"LEFT JOIN table_famille ON table_organe.Famille= table_famille.ID) " +   
"LEFT JOIN rle_orgposition ON table_organe.id = rle_orgposition.idOrgane";
```

The problem is about values I want to retrieve.
Thanks for your help !

(Sorry if my english isn't perfect, I'm not a native speaker) !

BIG EDIT: I don't know why, but In my instruction I just put brackets on SELECT... rle_orgposition.[position] and it worked.... why ? 
problem is solved, but it's still weird for me.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with c# and thus removing the tag

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried and the expected result values you would like?

Comment: get rid of the parentheses: `from table_organe left join table_famille on ... left join rle_orgposition on ...`

Comment: you can use `left join ... on left join ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple LEFT JOINs in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950296/how-to-use-multiple-left-joins-in-sql)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: var sql = @"
SELECT * FROM table_organe 
LEFT JOIN table_famille ON table_organe.Famille = table_famille.ID
LEFT JOIN rle_orgposition ON table_organe.id = rle_orgposition.idOrgane";

Comment: I tried the first instruction it didn't work, but the seconde work.

Comment: @Lec.Gael   i have update my answer  with suggestion for the reason the first query don't work but the second  work  ( or better don't raise an error)..

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong syntax `FROM (... ) LEFT`

```
 SELECT table_organe.id
  , table_famille.famille
  , table_organe.Libelle
  , table_organe.Description
  , table_organe.Symbole
  , rle_orgposition.position  
  FROM table_organe 
  LEFT JOIN table_famille ON table_organe.Famille= table_famille.ID
  LEFT JOIN rle_orgposition ON table_organe.id = rle_orgposition.idOrgane
```

Answer  updated for BIG EDIT  ..

the second  query work because you use select * (all column)  without mention any specified  column  name  .. 
In the first query  the use of the () FROM(  )  LEFT without a proper table alias the select with  named  column name  don't macth any alias  ..  and this raise an error ..

You can easly check using the query provided  above

Comment: @RaymondNijland  some word  is always done willingly .. it's a way to break the boredom ..  .. your comments are always welcome .. (I just didn't realize I used an ancient term).. many thanks ..

Comment: Well it indeed was meant as a joke to indeed break the boredom which happens more between (daily) stackoverflow regulars .. *"I just didn't realize I used an ancient term"* Also maybe you like do read ancients old english books that do i know

Answer (score 0):

C# code like this:

```
var statement = @"SELECT table_orgrane.id, table_orgrane.Famille
FROM table_organe
LEFT JOIN table_famille ON table_organe.Famille = table_famille.ID  
LEFT JOIN rle_orgposition ON table_organe.id = rle_orgposition.idOrgane";
```

use `columns` instead of `*`.

Comment: The instruction with a * is working, not the one with the specific parameters I want.

Comment: it is a best practice to void to use *, just consider your interesting columns.